# Retrofit: How to post encoded password with Base64?

Tags: base64, retrofit

I need to make a request with e-mail and password. E-mail and password are Strings sent to my repository class. And the password need to be encoded with Base64.

I'm using Retrofit 2.

I know I need to use `RequestBody` class, but how can I can make the request?

This is the code from Rest interface:

```
@POST("login")
Call<String> login(
    @Body RequestBody payload
);
```

In the repository, I have this to encode the password:

```
String encodedPassword = Base64.encodeToString(password.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

But I need to initialize the requestBody with the email and the encodedPassword variables, to make the request.

```
Call<String> call = getApi().login(requestBody);
```

Is this really the right way?

How the requestBody attribute is initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what your API expects.
If your API expects an object encoded as JSON/XML, you send it in the request body.

For login credentials, most common is to send them as FormUrlEncoded data.

As an example:

```
@POST("/posts")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<String> login(@Field("email") String email,
                   @Field("password") String password);
```

But as I said it all depends on what the API endpoint expects.

I also don't get why you need to Base64 encode the password, it doesn't add any additional security over the plain text over SSL, so you may double check this with the API documentation also.

Comment: Guy, thank you very much. It's exactly this way I needed. I don't know why sometimes we try the hardest way. =/
Really, Base64 does no add much security. This is not for a production app. Thank you again.